# Flight plan routing - when can you go direct?

Tags: flight-planning, routing

When you are creating a flight plan and getting a route from airport A to airport B, I noticed that in flight simulation the routes will mostly have a pattern of going to a waypoint --> then an airway --> to an exit waypoint --> to the next airway --> to the exit waypoint.  E.g. `KONAN UL607 KOK M150 GEBDA Y173 PABLA`

However, I also noticed that occasionally the flight plans will start routing direct from one waypoint to another (i.e. making up their own airways), e.g. `BIRGI DCT INGID DCT GOTAR DCT NALOX DCT PARAK`

Now what I don't understand is whether in the real world that is even allowed? If it is allowed, then in what circumstances can you do that and are their any rules and restrictions about doing it? E.g. if I want to route direct to another waypoint, then it must be within 10 NM of your current waypoint.

Comment: It would help if you included the jurisdiction (EuroControl, NavCanada, etc) so that answers can be specific to that system.

Comment: Well that's a good point, because I am programming routing algorithms that I want to work worldwide, I didn't even think there would be different rules in different regions? I'm trying to come up with an algorithm that can generate accurate routes across the world.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful to understand the Austria situation, I guess the answer is that it's fine to direct route, but it depends on where you are?

Comment: @KillerKode It will probably depend on where you are. I can't speak for anything other than USA flight plan processing, but I doubt the automation is consistent across jurisdictions.

Comment: The "also..." portion needs to be deleted and asked as a separate question. All SE sites work on a one-question-per-post basis...

Comment: Forgive me, the "also" is not an additional question but poorly presented here so it seems so.  I added the "also" part because I thought it may be a clue / related to the answer of my question.